# convert arraylist<Integer> to string via overridingtoString

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on an assignment for class it is to override the toString method in the ArrayList class by claling the toString() method of each list element and accumulating the results in a StringBuilder with the symbol "==>". I am stuck on how I override the toString method and actually convert the ArrayList which is an integer arraylist into a string arraylist to use for output.

Comment: SO is not for assignments!

Comment: Yes we are not here for doing your assignement. Juste extend ArrayList create toString with @Override annotation then iterrate your array, build the string in a StringBuilder then return it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not intend nor want the answer directly. I want hints because I am stuck on my assignment. I am new to coding and truly did not post strictly to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well not answering for your assignment though  giving you a hint

```
          array[j] = arrlist.get(somevar);
```

you can use get to do it manually

or you can use `toArray`